# How can I display the same panel multiple times?

Tags: sencha-touch, panel, extjs, carousel

I guess my question is so basic but I need help anyway.. the thing is.. I have a carousel with  5 cards (wich are panels) and inside this panel I want to call other panels that will be the same for all 5 cards..

To exemplify what I mean here's some samples of code:

```
//Here I'm creating the panel

this.testeCard(); 

MYPROJ.UI.prototype.testeCard = function(){
var teste = new Ext.Panel({
    html: 'teste teste teste',
    style: 'background-color: #2f7da8'
});
this._registerView(teste,'teste');
return teste;
};

//Here I'm calling it

MYPROJ.UI.prototype.currentCard = function(){
var currentCard = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'currentCard',
    cls: 'mainPanel',
    //html: 'currentCard',
    items:[
        this.getView('teste')   //Fine here
    ]
});        
this._registerView(currentCard, 'currentCard');
return currentCard;    
};

MYPROJ.UI.prototype.anotherCard = function(){
var currentCard = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'currentCard',
    cls: 'mainPanel',
    //html: 'currentCard',
    items:[
        this.getView('teste')   
    ]
});        
this._registerView(currentCard, 'currentCard');
return currentCard;    
};
```

So, what I want to do is to call this 'teste' card in both 'currentCard' and 'anotherCard'

How can I do it????

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you..

```
teste.show();
teste.setActiveItem(currentCard, 'slide');

teste.show();
teste.setActiveItem(anotherCard, 'slide');
```